# Phaser Image won't delete, maybe because I changed it's size or clarity?

Tags: image, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I'm working on an inventory system, for my game, and I'm having some trouble with the code that gets rid of used items. This is the code the makes visible items disappear, which is activated when the quest involving that item is completed:

```
if(tutorial == "complete"){
        this.spot = 0;
        while (this.spot < 18){
            if (this.pack[this.spot] == "key"){
                this.pack[this.spot] = null;
                break;
            }
            else {
                this.spot += 1;
            }
        }
            this.key.destroy();
}
```

For some reason the item that is displayed in the inventory, in this case a key, doesn't disappear when this code is triggered. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the following code, which makes the key appear in the first place:

```
if (this.pack[0] == "key"){
            this.key = this.physics.add.sprite(180, 150, 'key').setInteractive();
            this.key.body.immovable = true;
            this.key.body.allowGravity = false;
            this.key.setScale(4);
            this.key.texture.setFilter(Phaser.Textures.FilterMode.NEAREST);
}
```

I'm wondering the code that makes the image bigger or clearer is messing something up, but I'm aware it could easily be something else. Anyone know for sure?

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode employing arcade physics.

Comment: it depends where your code is placed. can you share more code? btw. why are you checking the first index `this.pack[0] == "key"`, the key could be in any slot or not?

Comment: This is sort of the test scenario. Once I perfect this, I'll replicate for all the other slots and items.

Comment: There is one more detail I can share. In the inventory scene, I added some code that displays text when an item in the inventory is selected. The text appears when I select the key when the tutorial quest isn't finished, but when that quest is set to complete and the image should disappear, selecting the image makes no text appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is in the `update` function, the problem that you are creating multiple images *(ever second)*, you should move the image creation into the `create` function, OR check if the `this.key` is set, like this only one image will be created.

```
if (this.pack[0] == "key" && this.key == null){
    this.key = this.physics.add.sprite(180, 150, 'key').setInteractive();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm too tired to post anymore, so I may have something tomorrow. I feel I should warn you, it may be a big one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. btw. if the problem is solved you don't need to post code, but for future question it is always good to add the information from where the code is called from the  `update` or `create` function.